# How can I enable/disable command in Visual Studio 2017 VSIX C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command, vsix, vsct

I'm developing an extension for Visual Studio 2017 using a C# VSIX project. 
I need to create a variable number of commands based on settings in a .ini file. 
I thought to create a maximum number of commands (because in a VSIX project every command needs a new .cs file), 
and enable only the commands written in the .ini file. Unfortunately I don't know how to disable a command.  I need to enable the commands when a boolean becomes true.

I've seen that I need to use the OleMenuCommand class, but I do not have Initialize() and StatusQuery() methods. How can I dynamically enable my commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable/disable commands in Visual Studio you can subscribe to the `BeforeQueryStatus` event of your `OleMenuCommand`:

```
myOleMenuCommand.BeforeQueryStatus += QueryCommandHandler;

private void QueryCommandHandler(object sender)
{
        var menuCommand = sender as Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleMenuCommand;
        if (menuCommand != null)
            menuCommand.Visible = menuCommand.Enabled = MyCommandStatus();
}
```

A possible implementation of `MyCommandStatus()` method can be:

```
public bool MyCommandStatus()
{
    // do this if you want to disable your commands when the solution is not loaded
    if (false == mDte.Solution.IsOpen)
      return false;

    // do this if you want to disable your commands when the Visual Studio build is running
    else if (true == VsBuildRunning)
      return false;

    // Write any condition here

    return true;

}
```

Comment: This is great, but @Ionut Enache how do I disable or enable the Run/Debug or Deploy menu options. eg. If a certain device isn't attached to the computer, I don't want them to be able to Deploy to it, because it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an [OleMenuCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.olemenucommand?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to add with OleMenuCommandService, you can subscribe to the [BeforeQueryStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.olemenucommand.beforequerystatus?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) event and inside it dynamically enable/disable the command:

```
    private void OnQueryStatus(object sender)
    {
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleMenuCommand menuCommand =
                sender as Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleMenuCommand;
            if (menuCommand != null)
                menuCommand.Visible = menuCommand.Enabled = MyCommandStatus();
    }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks but i don't understand if I manually have to create the  OnQueryStatus() method or if it is a already-existing method.

Comment: @cristianleonardi You have to create this method and use like this: myOleMenuCommand.BeforeQueryStatus +=  OnQueryStatus;