# VS2019 addin/extensions How do enable/disable menu item

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility, vsixmanifest

I am learning how to write VS2019 addin/extensions and searching for some good resource on specific questions like...

I am looking for some answers like,

1. How to i enable my menu item, only when a specific type of project is open or selected in a solution. ?
2. How do i iterate through files in a solution, How do i add files in a solution?
3. Is there any dom object available through which i can access items i need from XAML files.

Any good easy article answering above would be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. To enable/disable your menu items/commands, take a look at the `BeforeQuesryStatus` event. See my answer from here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/52059488/6775515
2. To iterate through the file, you need to use the [DTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.dte?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) interface. From there, you can access the [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.solution?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#EnvDTE__DTE_Solution) from where you can get all the projects, all the projects file, or the [selected files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.selecteditems?view=visualstudiosdk-2019#EnvDTE__DTE_SelectedItems) if this is what you want.
3. I didn't work with XAML files in a VSIX yet, but if anybody did it, please feel free to edit this answer in order to provide better response for the community. I would be curious too :)

Here is also a playlist of new videos from Microsoft: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EniQmgmMb6o&list=PLReL099Y5nRdG2n1PrY_tbCsUznoYvqkS

I think you will get better responses to your questions in the future if you will post a single question/issue in one post and not a series of questions.